# (Nios 2/Altera DE2 using Assembly) Why doesn't my lego controller motor receive the values from the sensor for self balancing robot?

Tags: assembly, robotics, intel-fpga, lego-mindstorms, nios

I am a computer science student and am working on a lab for school. I have been trying to make this work, to no avail. So far, All that happens is my motor runs forward without stopping. I connected my sensor to the LED's on the DE2 board to see if I was able to receive and store their values correctly, and that seems to be the case. However, the motor is not running in correspondence to the sensor. I have been tinkering around with this code for hours with no luck. I am an assembly programming noob and shall really appreciate your help with this.

I have attached my code here:

.equ ADDR, 0x10000070
.equ LEDR, 0x10000000
.equ LEDG, 0x10000010

.global main

main:

```
movia r22, LEDR
movia r23, LEDG
movia r8, ADDR
movia r9, 0x07f557ff
stwio r9, 4(r8)
```

sensor1:

```
movia r9, 0xfffffbff
stwio r9, 0(r8)
```

loop1:

```
ldwio r5, 0(r8) 
srli r5, r5, 11 
andi r5, r5, 0x1

bne r5, r0, loop1 

ldwio r10, 0(r8)
srli r10, r10, 27
andi r10, r10, 0x0f
stwio r10, 0(r22)
```

sensor2:

```
movia r9, 0xffffefff
stwio r9, 0(r8)
```

loop2:

```
ldwio r6, 0(r8) 
srli r6, r6, 13 
andi r6, r6, 0x1

bne r6, r0, loop2

ldwio r11, 0(r8)
srli r11, r11, 27
andi r11, r11, 0x0f
stwio r11, 0(r23)
```

motor:

```
/*beq r10, r11, motorOFF*/
blt r10, r11, motorR

movia r15, 0xfffffffc
stwio r15, 0(r8) 
br sensor1
```

motorR:

```
movia r15, 0xfffffffe
stwio r15, 0(r8)
br sensor1
```

.end

and here is a link to the lego controller manual:

http://www-ug.eecg.toronto.edu/msl/nios_devices/dev_newlegocontroller2.html

I am just trying to make this work for now, and then later I will have to use pulse width modulation to make it more accurate... I might have to use the nios2 timer?

I am lost and shall appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot guys, I really appreciate it.

Manik

Thanks a lot, I think I have been spending too much time on this and now this just needs a fresh pair of eyes to help me.